# Modifying global variables inside of POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, asynchronous

So I'm currently trying to make a simple quiz app for Github's [Noops Challenge](https://noopschallenge.com/) using their [Fizzbot API](https://noopschallenge.com/challenges/fizzbot).

I am storing and assembling the URL of the current question and next question in global variables.

```
var baseurl = "https://api.noopschallenge.com";
var nextQuestion = "/fizzbot/questions/1";
var url = "";
```

I have a submit function that sends a POST request to the server and receives the URL of the next question if the answer is correct.

```
function submit() {
    var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

            var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

        this.nextQuestion = response.nextQuestion; fizzbot
        this.url = baseurl + this.nextQuestion;

        console.log("Next Question: " + this.url);  
        }
    };

    xhttp.open("POST", this.url, true);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhttp.send(answer);

}
```

In addition to my submit button, I have a next button. After submitting a correct answer, the below function still prints https://api.noopschallenge.com/fizzbot/questions/1 to the log.

```
function next() {
    console.log(this.url);
}
```

I am pretty sure it has something to do with the asynchronous nature of the POST request, but am not sure what the best way to solve it is. I've posted a more complete snippet for a functioning example of what's happening.

```js
var question = "";
var baseurl = "https://api.noopschallenge.com";
var nextQuestion = "/fizzbot/questions/1";
var url = "";

function load() {
  this.url = this.baseurl + this.nextQuestion

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      this.question = response.message;

      document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = this.question;
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("GET", this.url, true);
  xhttp.send();
}

function submit() {

  var answer = document.getElementById("answer").value;
  var responseObject = {answer: answer}
  var responseJSON = JSON.stringify(responseObject);

  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      this.nextQuestion = response.nextQuestion;
      this.url = baseurl + this.nextQuestion;

      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = response.result;

      document.getElementById("nextQuestion").innerHTML = response.nextQuestion;

      console.log("Next Question: " + this.url);
    }
  };

  xhttp.open("POST", this.url, true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhttp.send(responseJSON);

}

function next() {
  console.log("URL to load: " + this.url);
  //GET request next question
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Noops Challenge | FizzBot Bot</title>
  <script src="Fizzbot.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body onload="load()">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
      <img src="https://noopschallenge.com/static/animation/fizzbot/images/img_3.png" width="30" height="30" class="d-inline-block align-top" alt=""> FizzBuzz Quiz
    </a>
    <!-- <span class="navbar-brand mb-0 h1">FizzBuzz Quiz</span> -->
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row" style="margin-top:5%;">
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-8">

        <div class="card">

          <div class="card-header">
            Question <span id="questionNumber">1</span>
          </div>

          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 id="question" class="card-title">Filler Question</h5><br> Answer: <input type="text" id="answer">
            <p class="card-text"><br> Result: <span id="result"></span><br> Next Question: <span id="nextQuestion"></span><br>
            </p>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit()" value="">Submit</button>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="next()" value="">Next</button>
          </div>

        </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>



</html>
```

Comment: what type of error are you seeing in the console? I suggest you read about "this"

Comment: No error, just printing out the old value. I've done some reading on the "this" keyword as well as reading on Asynchronous functions. I have a feeling it's because the function is asynchronous, but the weird part is that based on the log, the asynchronous function has already returned a value.

Comment: `this.url` in `xhttp.onreadystatechange` is probably not scoped to the right place for `xhttp.open()` to use it. If you declare `var nextUrl = ""` outside that `onreadystatechange` property and then set `nextUrl = response.nextQuestion` and then use this new var in your `xhttp.open()`, the scope should be correct. I don't like using `this` on it's own. I like the pattern of declaring what the hell `this` actually is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it had more to do with actual variable scope than it had to do with the async aspect of the code. Instead of dealing with a bunch of messy `this` references, I just put most of my globals inside of an object which ended up making more sense anyways.

Using an object with getters and setters I am able to access all of my variables throughout the code.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are stored in the `window` object. `this` can refer to `window` as well as pretty much any other object. Also, not using `this` might get you a global variable as well.

This will run in the global context:

```
function load() {
  this.url = this.baseurl + this.nextQuestion
```

Here `this` === `window`, so `this.url` is built from your global variables.

The context changes here:

```
  ...
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
      this.question = response.message;

      document.getElementById("question").innerHTML = this.question;
    }
  };
```

Here, `this` refers to the `xhttp` object. When setting `this.question`, you're creating a new property on `xhttp` and using that value to set the `<h5 id="question">` text. This works, it just doesn't change your global `question` variable.

This again uses the global variable:

```
  xhttp.open("GET", this.url, true);
  ...
}
```

Something alike happens when using the submit button:

```
function submit() {
  ...
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

      this.nextQuestion = response.nextQuestion;
      this.url = baseurl + this.nextQuestion;
```

Both `this.nextQuestion` and `this.url` create properties in this (new!) `xhttp` object. However, since you didn't put `this.` in front of `baseurl`, and there's no local variable with that name, the global variable will be used! So, implicitly you're doing this: `xhttp.url = window.baseurl + xhttp.nextQuestion`

That's why this will show a nice new full URL:

```
      console.log("Next Question: " + this.url);
    }
  };
```

But again, the request itself is still done using the initial URL, since we're leaving the `xhttp` scope and using the never changed global value here:

```
  xhttp.open("POST", this.url, true);
  ...
}
```

... and here:

```
function next() {
  console.log("URL to load: " + this.url);
  //GET request next question
}
```

Long story short: use `window.url` to set the global value inside another scope.

[About 'this' on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)